# redirect output to textbuffer in pygtk

Tags: python, pygtk

Is there anyway to redirect all the python output to a textview in pygtk

Example:

```
print "hi"  #It should insert "hi" into textview instead of printing in terminal
```

So how to set the textview as sys.stdout and sys.stderr?

PS: I have tried setting the stdout and stderr to a file and then read the file and add it to textview. But, is there a direct way so that I can output to textview directly?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite weird, in the sense that you add text to the text buffer (and not the textview) but using one of its available methods, e.g. set_text() which will replace the whole content (if present) with the new text, of insert() which will insert the text at the gtk.TextIter position (which identifies a position in the buffer)

As for redirecting the stdout to the buffer you can use the readline() method since it's a file like object and write the content to the buffer as explained before.

p.s. tyou should really use pygobject (or better PyGI) instead of pygtk, the latter is not maintained for over three years.